# Ada, raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : bad input for 'Value: "well."

Tags: ada

I am unable to get the following script to return my input value; I've looked up ARM as well as John Barnes book but to no avail. In theory it should work.
Anyone know why? I'm a newby so the Barnes book and the ARM are probably too advanced for me.

```
 with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure ron is
A : Character;

begin
    Put_Line ("Hi Ron, how are you?");
        A := Character'Value (Get_Line);
    Put_Line ("So you feel" &
        Character'Image (A));
end ron;

--TERMINAL OUTPUT
--ronhans@amante ~/Desktop $ gnatmake -gnat2012 ron.adb
--gcc-4.8 -c -gnat2012 ron.adb
--gnatbind -x ron.ali
--gnatlink ron.ali
--ronhans@amante ~/Desktop $ ./ron
--Hi Ron, how are you?
--well.

--raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : bad input for 'Value: "well."
```

Comment: The value is a *string*, doesn't fit into a *character*.

Comment: What did you expect the program to print out? I’m guessing you wanted `So you feel well.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the LRM, you will see that `Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line` returns a `String`:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Ron is
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Hi Ron, how are you?");

   declare
      Reply : constant String := Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line;
   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("So you feel " & Reply & "?");
   end;
end Ron;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with you program is that you try to put an array of characters into a single character. Instead of of using `A : Character`, try to define an array type something like

```
type Character_Array_T (1 .. 10) of Character;
...    
A : Character_Array_T;
```

or use

```
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
...
A : Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String;
```

I suggest the use of an unbounded string, so that the input is not bounded to some specific string length, if your intention is to read out an input several times. Ada type `string` requires you to specify the string length and this length is exactly the number of characters this string should contain.

See [Wiki, unbounded strings](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Libraries/Ada.Strings.Unbounded) and [Unbounded string handling](https://www2.adacore.com/gap-static/GNAT_Book/html/aarm/AA-A-4-5.html) for the reference.